# ImageProcessor.Web on .Net Core 2.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, imageprocessor

Can i use the imageprocessor.Web on .net Core 2.0 project even if the it's restored, targeting .NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1?

**Update**

On a fresh .Net Core 2.0 project the following Packages where installed:
imageprocessor
imageprocessor.web
imageprocessor.web.config

Normally on a Asp.net Mvc Template (framework=v4.6.1) by creating simple markup for images such as `<img alt="Picture for category Electronics" src="http://localhost:15536/images/thumbs/0000005_electronics_600.jpeg?crop=0.5,0,0,0.1&amp;cropmode=percentage" title="Show products in category Electronics">` in any view would crop an image base on the querystrings provided in the url of the image, as specified in the documentation: http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/imageprocessingmodule/crop/ however

A: None of the query strings provided take any affect whatsoever 
B: When attempted to also add the configuration file by installing the nuget package ImageProcessor.Web.Config the App.Config isn't edited and am left with nothing to configure

All I need is some simple image processing done on images as described by the imageprocessor.web documentation here: http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Basically the normally functionality that you would expect doesn't seem to be applying, im simply appending a query string "?crop=0.5,0,0.1,0&cropmode=percentage" to an image and nothing happens, im wondering if this is even compatible

Comment: I Successfully installed the imageprocessor and imageprocessor.web onto a Fresh Project yes, however none of the query strings seem to be taking any effect

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly

Comment: Accordingly?  Your question still does not contain a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot.

Imageprocessor.Web is built against .NET 4.5.2 which is a completely different target framework specific to Windows desktop. You need something that targets either a netstandard or .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: What would possibly suggest that it would be ever targeting Core? 

It never will, it depends on System.Web, I've archived the repository and recommend using ImageSharp.Web for ASP.NET Core projects.

Comment: What can we use instead?

Comment: I've specifically written ImageSharp.Web to replace it. See the comment above yours ↑.