# Generic GDI+ Error on Saving/loading image from MemoryStream using ImageProcessor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, imageprocessor

I'm having Generic GDI+ Error on line imageFactory.Load(inStream). My project is ASP.NET Core Razor-Pages.

I tried to clone inStream to new stream (this helped me before when saving bitmaps), but to no success.

Anyone dealt with something similar before?

```
// using ImageProcessor;
// using ImageProcessor.Imaging.Formats;

byte[] photoBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\img\img.jpg");
            ISupportedImageFormat format = new JpegFormat();
            Size size = new Size(200,200);
            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(photoBytes))
            {
                using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var asd = inStream;

                    using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true))
                    {
                        imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                            .Resize(size)
                            .Format(format)
                            .Save(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ImgAdjusted\");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: 1. `ImageProcessor` is not designed for `.NET Core` , see [the author's answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50168251/10091607).  2. `ImageProcessor` is in maintainance mode only . Focus for the ImageProcessor libraries has switched to a new library `ImageSharp`

Comment: Strange - in another thread I read this is prefered package to handle image processing in .net core. Thumbs up though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @itminus answer - this library is not designed to work in .net core.

Answer (score 2):

Top 3 alternatives to `ImageProcessor` for .NET Core

- [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common) : Cross platform GDI+
- [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) : Cross Platform GDI+
- Magick.NET - Windows Only

Aside: Where did `System.Drawing.Common` come from?
.NET Core did not initially support GDI+. Then, they came out with the windows comparability library, which would get you GDI+ on windows only.  At the time of writing Microsoft has ported the GDI+ functionality using a Mono implementation.